# How to get a reference to an HTML element that only exists in memory

Tags: javascript, dom, html5-video, userscripts, getelementsbytagname

First, a little background on the question.

After I found [this](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Closed-Ideas/Music-Ability-to-change-the-Speed-of-Tracks/idi-p/63567) Spotify Community idea being throwed away, I've decided to check out the Web App's inner workings to figure out some way of changing the playback speed.

Turns out Spotify's Web Player uses a regular HTML5 `video` tag created by runtime JavaScript, which means I can tinker with it's `playbackRate` property. I'm able to reference it through the DevTools debugger and it all works.

But the element's reference is hidden behing uglified code and factory functions, so I can't grab it by regular user scripting. Also, the element never gets inserted into the DOM (`parentElement` is `null`), so `document.getElementsByTagName()` also won't work.

---

TL;DR: Is there a way of referencing a DOM Element that wasn't inserted into the page/only exists in memory?

I've made a simple working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/moty0paw/). Once you press the button, a video tag is created but not inserted into the page. You can't reference it.

Comment: Nope, you can't

Comment: I'm able to add some breakpoints throughout the code and then get a reference from inside the private functions. Any way this could be automated through a userscript?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my specific problem by replacing the **document.createElement** function with a wrapper function. Inside of this wrapper I check for a specific HTML tag and store it globally so I can access it later.

I'm using Tampermonkey on Chrome 81.0.4044.138.
Here's the relevant code:

```
const originalCreateElement = document.createElement;

document.createElement = function() {
  const ret = originalCreateElement.apply(document, arguments)

  if(arguments[0] == 'video'){
    document.videotag = ret;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

By using this method one may store every single tag created on a global array.